# Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header : 7371007E

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, tcp

I am working on a program for FTP Transfer implementation, when I tried to send a list of files in the server from the server to client, it is working fine for the first time but it is throwing below error if I send command list files a second time.

```
Exception in thread "main" `java.io.StreamCorruptedException`: invalid stream header: 7371007E
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808                                                                                        )
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
at transferfileClient.ListFiles(ListClient.java:142)
at transferfileClient.displayMenu(ListClient.java:206)
at ListClient.main(ListClient.java:15)
```

Here is my server side code:

```
public void Listfiles() throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<String> MyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File folder = new File("//home//cci100//CN");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    String NameOfFiles;
    String temp;
    int ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) { 
        if(listOfFiles[i].isFile()){
            MyList.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }     
    }       
    try{
        objectOutput.writeObject(MyList);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my Client side code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void ListFiles() throws Exception{
    ArrayList<String> MyListc = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f=new File("//home//cci100//CN");

    FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(f);
    objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(ClientSoc.getInputStream());
    try {
        Object object = objectInput.readObject();
        MyListc =  (ArrayList<String>) object;
        int s=MyListc.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < MyListc.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(MyListc.get(i));
        }
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed your crazy formatting. Don't do that. Please use a consistent and correct formatting and indentation style. Illegible otherwise. [tag:socket.io] has exactly nothing to do with it. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: I am sorry, I am learning.

Comment: It's for your own good as well as ours, not just when posting here but when writing and then reading your own code. You won't understand code that isn't formatted correctly, or rather trying to understand it requires extra wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` for the life of the socket.